# Count and group records through three associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have three models:

- Book [belongs_to :author]
- Author [belongs_to :publisher, has_many :books]
- Publisher [has_many :authors]

I want to know how many Books have every Publisher, grouped by Publisher and ordered by Publishers with most Books. I need to get a list with a single query, where I can get something like:

- Publisher ABC: 3800 books
- Publisher XYZ: 1922 books
- Publisher JKL: 192 books
- *and so on*

Books belongs to Author but not to Publisher directly —complicated to explain why. Is there a easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`has_many through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) to define a relation between `publisher` and `books` like this

```
# publisher.rb

has_many :books, :through => :authors
```

Then you get the ordered count like this

```
records =  Publisher.joins(:books).
                     group("publishers.id").
                     select("publishers.*, COUNT(*) AS books_count").
                     order("books_count DESC")
# => access book count as record.book_count
```

If you need to access the books count for publisher often then look into adding a column called `books_count`in publishers table  (to improve performance). You can update it using [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=asciicast)

Comment: Thank you. Works very well. I wanted avoid to add another column and store the amount, but I will check the counter cache thing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
counts = Publisher.joins(:authors => :books).
                   select('publishers.id, count(books.id) as number').
                   group('publishers.id')
# count[0] is now a Publisher object; and counts[0].number is the count of books they own
```